# What are event and UI parameters in Dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, dialog

What are  event and UI parameters in jQuery Dialog? Can I get a mouse position using them?

```
$( ".selector" ).dialog({
   open: function(event, ui) { ... }
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `event` parameter is the [DOM Event object](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_event.asp). The `ui` parameter is typically a hash; its properties depend on the event being raised.
For the dialog `open` event, both arguments appear to be null. For other events, such as `dragStart`, `drag` and `dragStop`, `ui` will contain the current position and offset:

```
$('.selector').dialog({
    drag: function(event, ui) {
        console.log("Current position: " + ui.position);
    }
});
```

Comment: Is there any documentation with a complete list of what's on these objects?